# Rig rest position in Vertex Paint?

Tags: rigging, vertices, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

Is there any way to display the rig in it's resting position only in Vertex Paint? The rig is pre-posed to a position I want however since the hands are curling inwards, I can't see the entirety of the hand to paint on. Is there any way to just keep it in pose mode for vertex paint then switch it back?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go to the armature properties in the properties editor, and near the top there will be a Radio button between “pose position“ and “rest position.“ switch it to rest position to temporarily hide the pose as it were.